# In brainfuck, how does the interpreter deal with going below 0 in the tape?

Tags: brainfuck

I am not sure that I understand what exactly the interpreter does to handle moving the current index of the tape below zero. Should the interpreter allow the tape to go below 0? Thank you!

Comment: The first question in the title might be on topic, but asking whether your version should go below 0 is off-topic as primarily opinion based. I recommend removing that part and emphasizing the title question. Having said that, thanks for the BF question! See "implementation issues" and "conventions" sections at https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is simply undefined behavior. Some allow it, although most don't, because it's simpler to implement that way.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide a set of options for a programmer on strategy how to handle out-of-range cases. See my Brainfuck engine and how I resolved this issue.[Brainfuck Runner](https://github.com/nikolayresh/Brainfuck-Runner)